# wpf application does not check for updates when installing

Tags: wpf, publish

I have a WPF application which is running for few months now, i updated some code today and published it to server .Now when my client tries to hit the url to download or clicks the application shortcut in desktop a previous version which was deployed few months ago runs and the latest code is not updated .In my project ,properites ->publish settings->Updates .I have selected the option "the application should check for updates " .Please find below the image containing the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ,we have to set "specify a minimum required version for the application" to the latest one [image]